# How to reuse a goroutine instead of creating a new goroutine for reach async call

Tags: go, asynchronous, goroutine, pool

For this use case, it seems like it might be valid:
This is dumbed down code, but you should get the idea -

```
func Log(v interface{}){

  1. get json - json marshal some large object v
  2. write big buf to a file 

}
```

.. the above ^^ could be pretty blocking, so maybe want to put in a goroutine:

```
func Log(v interface{}){

  go func(){
    1. get json - json marshal some large object v
    2. write big buf to a file (not necessarily stdout)
  }()

}
```

but the problem with that is we are creating a lot of goroutines here, which might defeat the purpose of putting it in a goroutine anyway.

So my question is - is there a way to somehow use a pool of goroutines, and use those. Even just like 10 in a pool would be fabulous.

I assume using channels to communicate with them, but not sure exactly how

Two stipulations:

1. only need 1 job to be added to the queue at a time (but they are added asynchronously)
2. if the queue is full, I want to just run on a new goroutine separately, not adding a new worker to the queue

Comment: One of the basic concurrency patterns is a "worker pool": (https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: added 2 stipulations to OP

Comment: When you are saying "I want to just run it separately, not adding a new worker to the queue", are you referring to running it a blocking way, or run it in its own goroutine?

Comment: If the queue is full, I dont use a worker, I just run the next job with a goroutine.  So I guess conceptually it's trying to reuse goroutines, but if it can't, just creates a new one. I tagged your name in my code below (in my answer),

Comment: @AlexanderMills, if you're going to run extra calls in a new goroutine anyway, there's little point to trying to reuse a few goroutines. Let the runtime manage the resources, and dispatch goroutines as necessary in your code.

Comment: @JimB that's probably true, especially if all 20 were blocked up momentarily and it created like 100 more lol, I see your point. So is there ever a point in reusing go-routines?

Comment: @AlexanderMills. a worker pool is typically used to setup a specific amount of concurrency, and give backpressure when all goroutines are busy. A worker pool is also so simple, it makes some concurrency patterns easier to deal with. In rarer cases, goroutines are cheap, but they are not free, so in some very high throughput situations that goroutine overhead may show up. In that case a worker pool removes some of that overhead, but even network servers will dispatch a goroutine per request, so it's still something to validate with benchmarks before optimizing

Comment: @AlexanderMills if your only concern is the overhead of creating a goroutine, no, there is no reason at all to do this. Just make a new goroutine whenever you need one. The only reason in practice for worker pooling is intentionally bottlenecking concurrency.

Comment: @Adrian that makes sense - I guess only way to know for sure is it to test it and see if reusing 100 goroutines (for a particular task) is better than spawning new ones willy nilly, hard to say, depends a bit on closure stuff etc. Certainly a looot simpler in terms of coding to just create a new one with no pooling

Comment: @AlexanderMills goroutines are extremely lightweight by design, and the Go stdlib creates them freely, and the language encourages doing the same; avoiding them for performance reasons is definitively premature optimization. Just use them normally and worry about performance problems when you actually measure a performance problem.

Comment: @Adrian in prod, we are gonna be logging about 1000 per second if things go well. I just can't imagine creating 1000 goroutines per second is gonna be faster than re-using some. TBD. Each logging call is creating a buffer and that writing buffer to file. It should run on a goroutine. But we will see if re-using is useful at all.

Comment: and contrary to what @JimB says, my original design is good - it's a race to see if the 30 goroutines in the pool can perform well enough that I don't need to run new jobs on new goroutines (which I will if the queue is full) (I aint coding dynamically adding or remove workers!)

Answer (score -2):

This code basically works. If we were just writing to stdout, then this really would be unnecessary, but since we are writing to multiple files, then could benefit from some goroutine stuff.

```
package pool

import (
    "sync"
)

type ChanMessage struct {
    f  func(*sync.WaitGroup)
    wg *sync.WaitGroup
}

type Worker struct {
    c      chan *ChanMessage
    mtx    sync.Mutex
    isBusy bool
}

type Pool struct {
    mtx               *sync.Mutex
    Size              int
    workers           []*Worker
    Count             int
    RoundRobinCounter int
}

func (p *Pool) createWorkers() {

    for i := 0; i < p.Size; i++ {

        var w = &Worker{
            c:      make(chan *ChanMessage, 1),
            mtx:    sync.Mutex{},
            isBusy: false,
        }

        go func(w *Worker) {
            for {
                var m = <-w.c
                w.mtx.Lock()
                w.isBusy = true
                p.Count++
                m.f(m.wg)
                m.wg.Wait()
                p.Count--
                w.isBusy = false
                w.mtx.Unlock()
            }
        }(w)

        p.workers = append(p.workers, w)
    }
}

func CreatePool(size int) *Pool {

    var p = &Pool{
        mtx:               &sync.Mutex{},
        Size:              size,
        Count:             0,
        RoundRobinCounter: size + 1,
    }

    p.createWorkers()

    return p
}

func (p *Pool) Run(z func(*sync.WaitGroup)) {

    p.mtx.Lock()

    var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    if p.Count >= p.Size {
        p.mtx.Unlock()
        // queue is full, so just create a new goroutine here
        go z(wg)
        return
    }

    var m = &ChanMessage{
        f:  z,
        wg: wg,
    }

    for _, v := range p.workers {
        if !v.isBusy {
            v.mtx.Lock()
            p.mtx.Unlock()
            v.isBusy = true
            v.mtx.Unlock()
            v.c <- m
            return
        }
    }

    // couldn't find a non-busy one, so just round robin to next
    p.RoundRobinCounter = (p.RoundRobinCounter + 1) % p.Size
    var v = p.workers[p.RoundRobinCounter]

    p.mtx.Unlock()

    v.mtx.Lock()
    v.isBusy = true
    v.mtx.Unlock()

    v.c <- m

}
```

here is a test:

```
package pool_test

import (
    "github.com/oresoftware/json-logging/jlog/pool"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

// Test if the worker pool can handle a simple task
func TestWorkerPoolSimpleTask(t *testing.T) {
    poolSize := 3
    p := pool.CreatePool(poolSize)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    p.Run(func(g *sync.WaitGroup) {
        // Perform a simple task
        t.Logf("Simple task executed")
        g.Done()
        wg.Done()
    })

    // Ensure the pool count is updated correctly
    if p.Count != 0 {
        t.Errorf("Expected pool count to be 0, got %d", p.Count)
    }
}

// Test if the worker pool can handle multiple concurrent tasks
func TestWorkerPoolConcurrentTasks(t *testing.T) {
    poolSize := 5
    p := pool.CreatePool(poolSize)

    numTasks := 10
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numTasks)

    for i := 0; i < numTasks; i++ {
        go func(index int) {
            p.Run(func(g *sync.WaitGroup) {
                // Perform a task and log the index
                t.Logf("Task %d executed", index)
                g.Done()
                wg.Done()
            })
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    // Ensure the pool count is updated correctly
    if p.Count != 0 {
        t.Errorf("Expected pool count to be 0, got %d", p.Count)
    }
}

// Test if the worker pool can handle more tasks than the pool size
func TestWorkerPoolFullQueue(t *testing.T) {
    poolSize := 3
    p := pool.CreatePool(poolSize)

    numTasks := 5
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numTasks)

    for i := 0; i < numTasks; i++ {
        go func(index int) {
            p.Run(func(g *sync.WaitGroup) {
                // Perform a task and log the index
                t.Logf("Task %d executed", index)
                time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond) // Simulate task execution time
                g.Done()
                wg.Done()
            })
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    // Ensure the pool count is updated correctly
    if p.Count != 0 {
        t.Errorf("Expected pool count to be 0, got %d", p.Count)
    }
}

// Test if the worker pool handles a large number of tasks without deadlocks or panics
func TestWorkerPoolStressTest(t *testing.T) {
    poolSize := 10
    p := pool.CreatePool(poolSize)

    numTasks := 1000
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numTasks)

    for i := 0; i < numTasks; i++ {
        go func(index int) {
            p.Run(func(g *sync.WaitGroup) {
                // Perform a task and log the index
                t.Logf("Task %d executed", index)
                g.Done()
                wg.Done()
            })
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    // Ensure the pool count is updated correctly
    if p.Count != 0 {
        t.Errorf("Expected pool count to be 0, got %d", p.Count)
    }
}
```

and here is the real world use case:

```
func (l *Logger) writeJSON(level shared.LogLevel, mf *MetaFields, args *[]interface{}) {

    date := time.Now().UTC().String()
    date = date[:26]
    var strLevel = shared.LevelToString[level]
    var pid = shared.PID

    if mf == nil {
        mf = NewMetaFields(&MF{})
    }

    shared.StdioPool.Run(func(g *sync.WaitGroup) {

        // TODO: maybe manually generating JSON is better? prob not worth it
        buf, err := json.Marshal([8]interface{}{"@bunion:v1", l.AppName, strLevel, pid, l.HostName, date, mf.m, args})

        if err != nil {

            _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(3)
            DefaultLogger.Warn("could not marshal the slice:", err.Error(), "file://"+file+":"+strconv.Itoa(line))

            //cleaned := make([]interface{},0)

            var cache = map[*interface{}]*interface{}{}
            var cleaned = make([]interface{}, 0)

            for i := 0; i < len(*args); i++ {
                // TODO: for now instead of cleanUp, we can ust fmt.Sprintf()
                v := &(*args)[i]
                c := hlpr.CleanUp(v, &cache)
                //debug.PrintStack()
                cleaned = append(cleaned, c)
            }

            buf, err = json.Marshal([8]interface{}{"@bunion:v1", l.AppName, level, pid, l.HostName, date, mf.m, cleaned})

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(errors.New("Json-Logging: could not marshal the slice: " + err.Error()))
                g.Done()
                return
            }
        }

        shared.M1.Lock()
        safeStdout.Write(buf)
        safeStdout.Write([]byte("\n"))
        shared.M1.Unlock()
        g.Done()

    })

}
```

in my case I don't need the waitgroup, since it's all synced out code, but having the wg makes it more generic.

Comment: This is a poor example of concurrency in Go, resulting in multiple data races (always test with the race detector). You are trying to replicate basic functionality of channels using locks and flags. If you want to use a worker pool, see the how the example above is structured, and leverage the builtin channels and `select` to do the synchronization and communication.

Comment: sure, I bet it has holes, as locking with golang is always a challenge. Can you show me how you use race detector? sounds cool. However, the gist of the code is fine.

Comment: To enable the race detector, use the `-race` flag when building or testing your package.

Comment: To find out if a lock is locked or channel is full, I need a boolean to read that value, because Go does not let you (sometimes for good reason) check if a lock is locked or channel is full. I don't really believe in shared memory languages like this.

Comment: There are good reasons for that, some of which your code suffers from. Primarily it creates logical race conditions (different from data races) like [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). If you need to check if you can send on a channel, that's built into the language with `select`.

Comment: ok Jim, I did your select thing, not sure if it's functional better but I could delete some locks I guess - https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/acf03246abcafddd6c27196b8a614607